# Which commands/packages remove listoffigures from ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

How can I remove list of figures and list of tables from ToC? I read much questions about how to add them to the ToC. But indeed I have the problem that they are added and I don't want them to appear them.

I use the documentclass `report`.

```
\documentclass[
        paper=a4,
      twoside=false,
     10pt,
          titlepage,
          plainheadsepline,
          plainfootsepline,
          headsepline,
          footsepline,
    titlepage=false,
             abstracton,
             ngerman
]{report}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

These are my first commands in the file. I don't know what does add them to the ToC.

I produce the ToC and list of figures here:

```
\begin{document}
\input{titlepage}\clearpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{abstract}
\startprintinglogo
\tableofcontents\clearpage
\printglossary\clearpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abkürzungsverzeichnis}]\clearpage
\listoffigures\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings\clearpage
```

The list of listings and the glossaries aren't added to the ToC - just the list of figures and the list of tables. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

See section 2 of the `tocbibind` documentation.

Comment: Just thanks! Should have read the documentation of ```tocbibind``` instead of pasting the part I needed to add the bibliography to toc ..